# Is there a way to incrementally update Dask metadata file?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, fastparquet, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to process a dataset and make incremental updates as writing it out in Dask. The Dask metadata file would help a lot when it comes to rereading the processed data. However, as I write new partitions/subsets to the same path, the metadata there gets overwritten by the new partitions/subsets rather than updated with them included.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet(read_path)
# some transformations
df = …
df.to_parquet(write_path, partition_on=[col1, col2, …], write_metadata_file=True)
```

Looked at a few places and haven't found an obvious way to do this. Does anyone know if anyone has done something that handles such a use case? Could be either incrementally update the metadata files or make edits to/combine a few of them. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is specific to the `fastparquet` engine (works fine in `pyarrow`).

Answer (score 0):

Dask's `to_parquet()` method has an `append` mode which I think is exactly what you want here:

```
append : bool, optional

    If False (default), construct data-set from scratch.
    If True, add new row-group(s) to an existing data-set.
    In the latter case, the data-set must exist, and the schema must match the input data.
```

I have used this successfully with the `pyarrow` engine, version `1.0.1`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried using `append`. While it does incrementally update the partitions/subsets, it doesn't incrementally update the `_metadata` file, which is what I hope to do. The `_metadata` gets overwritten even in `append` mode.

Comment: Huh, my usage of append mode leads to the metadata file being updated correctly. what engine are you using? I've had no problems using `pyarrow`.

Comment: Just to be clear - the `_metadata` file will always be overwritten, but I understand you mean that the new `_metadata` file after doing an `append` ignores the pre-existing partitions?

Comment: I was using `fastparquet`. And yes, I mean the new `_metadata` file would ignore the pre-existing partitions rather than add the new partitions to the pre-existing ones. To be clear, did you get it to work correctly (i.e. `_metadata` gets overwritten consistently with all partitions in the directory) while using the `pyarrow` engine?

Comment: Yep, I have test written/appended/read many datasets and it has worked for me every time, using `pyarrow==1.0.1`

Comment: Yeah, can confirm `pyarrow` works fine. Seems to be a `fastparquet`-specific issue. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It would be great if you could raise an issue on the `fastparquet` repo to track this! https://github.com/dask/fastparquet